# Adding an array to a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have some code I want to put into a JSON object ultimately. But first I want to create a javascript object and within that object add an array of values. Sounds simple enough but my approach seems wrong. First I create a basic object, the set a few fields. Lastly, iterate over a bunch of checkboxes and then, if one is checked at that value to an array.

At the last step I need to add that array to my object (myData) and then JSONify it.

Any ideas how I can do this, seems myData.push(filters); doesn't work...

Note that the object itself is not an array, I want to place an array IN the object.

```
       var myData = new Object();

        myData.deviceId = equipId;

        myData.dateTo = dateTo
        myData.dateFrom = dateFrom;
        myData.numResults = $("#numResults").val();
        var i=0;
        var filters = [];
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
               if (this.checked) {
                   allData += $(this).val() + ",";
                    filters[i] = {
                        filterIds: $(this).val()
                    };
                    ++i;
               }
            });

        myData.push(filters);
```

Comment: Push is not for Objects, it's for Arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how to add items to an Object, change

`myData.push(filters);`

to

`myData.filters = filters;`

Also, maybe change `= new Object` to `= {}`.  There's no difference, but it's easier to read, because literal notation takes up less space.

Read more about [**Array.prototype.push**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 0):

Use `push` to add elements to the `filters` array. Use property assignment to add another property to the `myData` object.

```
    var myData = {
        deviceId: equipId,
        dateTo: dateTo,
        dateFrom: dateFrom,
        numResults: $("#numResults").val()
    };
    var filters = [];
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            allData += $(this).val() + ",";
            filters.push({
                filterIds: $(this).val()
            });
        }
    });

    myData.filters = filters;
```

BTW, don't use `new Object()` to create an object, use `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the need for an extra array and i.

```
var myData = {}

myData.deviceId = equipId;

myData.dateTo = dateTo
myData.dateFrom = dateFrom;
myData.numResults = $("#numResults").val();
myData.filters = [];
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        allData += $(this).val() + ",";
        myData.filters.push({
            filterIds: $(this).val()
        });
    }
});
```